# Golang Simple User Input Product Math Question like 3*2*1 = 6

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a small program that allows a user to input an integer which will output the product such as follows:

For example:

```
a = 5, 5*4*3*2 = 120
a = 4, 4*3*2*1 = 24  
a = 3, 3*2*1 = 6
```

Can someone provide guidance as I'm stuck on how to frame this more efficiently.  If using Python, I would probably write the logic something like:

```
def a(num):
    x = 1
    for i in range (num):
            x=x*(i + 1)
    return x

print a(5)
```

Comment: Sure -- and that'd work in Python. How would you approach this in Golang? The two approaches aren't that different

Comment: Can you post your attempt or say what part in particular you are confused about?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  The responses by xspare and myxaxa were very helpful to answer my question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about the go language itself first, after that you'll be able to convert your python code into go, *easily*.

Few go learning resources:

- https://tour.golang.org
- https://gobyexample.com
- https://golang.org/doc

---

But anyway, here is the go version of your python code:

```
func a(num int) int {
    x := 1
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        x = x * (i + 1)
    }
    return x
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(a(5)) // 120
    fmt.Println(a(4)) // 24
    fmt.Println(a(3)) // 6
}
```

Working playground: https://play.golang.org/p/glHwuMhTDYj

Answer (score 0):

the main function taken from previous answer - only the scanf added here as you requested

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func a(num int) int {
    x := 1
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        x = x * (i + 1)
    }
    return x
}

func main() {
    var i int
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
    if nil == err {
        fmt.Println(a(i))
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```